# Android deep link not working ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-deep-link

I've placed a deep link in my manifest using (I think) the format from the documentation

```
 <activity
            android:name="my.package.name.AInviteFriends"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_a_invite_friends"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

            <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_invite_friends">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

                <data
                    android:scheme="my.package.name" /custom scheme I was told to use
                    android:host="companyurl.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/invite_friends"
                     />

            </intent-filter>


</activity>
```

I then navigate to this URL *from within the app*, hoping for it to be intercepted and go to the activity. I'm not sure why we're using deep links instead of a normal intent, I think it's for tracking or something:

my.package.name://company.com/invite_friends

But when I try this, the browser opens with a Webpage not available/ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME error. What am I missing about this intent?

Comment: you can't use the . in scheme see the answer written by @LiazKamper

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure you can use an 'address-like' scheme.
I would start with a simple scheme, e.g 'mygreatapp' (the URI is mygreatapp://) and no host or pathPrefix.
See how it works for you and go from there

Comment: Thank you for your response. Using just
  
android:scheme="http"

and the URL

http:// company.com/invite_friends

It goes to my company's 404 page, unintercepted.

Comment: Sorry for late response. What happens when you try just
```
<data
                    android:scheme="my.package.name" /custom scheme I was told to use
                    android:host="companyurl.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/invite_friends"
                     />
```